# Excel docs not opening on random pcs

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, windows-xp, 64-bit, microsoft-office

We have a xls file on our network being sent via outlook that some pcs will open and some will not. The original document was created on windows 7 64 bit in office 2007. It has opened on another windows 7 64 bit and windows xp, both running office 2010. It has failed to open on windows 7 64 bit, windows 7 32 bit, and a separate windows xp(both win7 were running office 2010 and the xp machine was running office 2007). On the pcs it will not open directly from the email on you can save the xls file to the local machine and it will open that way. What is going on here? Has anyone else seen this before?

Comment: Unless you're using just a viewer that's associated MS Office files, you generally can't open these files directly by clicking on them from within an email program or browser.  They typically need to be saved to your hard drive and then opened there.  So the fact that you can open them directly on some machines is the more surprising.

Comment: The file is saved to a shared network drive. This is why we can open the document from the email.